# Static variable lifespan in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, static-variables

Will the static variable declared in a recursive function be destroyed once the first return executes?
For example:

```
int func(int x) {
    static int n;
    // recursive call
}
```

Comment: Static variables are destroyed on program exit. They are initialized when the code is first encountered.

Comment: Just so that the duplicate makes more sense - the fact that function is recursive have no effect on lifetime of a static variable.